# Setting number of bars in histogram using QGIS

Tags: spatial-statistics

I am using QGIS 2 "Statist" to build a histogram for my data. I see that I can set the band width of the bars, but it seems that "Statist" does not provide the option of setting the number of bars.

How do I set the number of bars in a histogram?